# How can I recover the files on an SDXC flash card from a suddenly dead Galaxy Note 2?

Tags: virtualbox, mount, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to recover the files on an SDXC card (SanDisk 64GB) that was in a Galaxy Note II. The Note 2 itself died suddenly, and it doesn't seem recoverable. Rather than seek another Galaxy just to read the SD card, I'd like to read the files from a Linux VM (CentOS 64) launched from VirtualBox. This is promising because Disk Utility on my OS X (Yosemite) shows that it recognizes the SD card:

[image: Disk Utility]

But the disk is not actually mounted. After switching CentOS on, the disk is no longer visible:

[image: CentOS running on VirtualBox]

How do I mount the SD card, reported by Disk Utility to be formatted in Windows_FAT_32, long enough to copy the files?

Comment: I presume this is a Linux driver problem with the card reader itself.  An easier solution is to use one of the [trial Windows vbox virtual machines](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/), avoid the driver problem all together, skip trying to figure out CentOS FAT32 support all together.

Comment: Interesting.. You're right... It may very well be that the card reader driver is missing. I'm downloading as I type one of the virtual machines you point to. Even though they are labeled IE (Internet Explorer), I'm guessing that they include Windows Explorer under the same shrinkwrap (?).

Comment: The virtual machines are labeled IE because they are generated for the purpose of testing, websites, with past versions of IE.  Are you not familiar with Windows, or Windows Explorer, which is basically, the equivalent of what ever OS X calls its shell and window management system.

Comment: I see. So the IEs are released to help developers who choose Macs and Linux boxes so they can cater to Windows users. OS X's Finder is equivalent to Windows Explorer. Once again: presumably there is a Windows Explorer inside each Internet Explorer zip archive. I'm still stuck with how to unpack the zip64 archives. Even a recent unzip is unable to unpack them.

Comment: All versions of Windows by default uses Windows Explorer, it isn't "included", it's simply the default just like Finder is the default.  No; these boxes are used for web developers, any web developer, to test against IE.  You understand those are VMs right of a trial installation of Windows good for 90 days,right?